# Catch headset pause/play keypresses in Windows

Tags: windows-8, audio, microphone, key-binding

I have a new Ultrabook which has single audio jack for input and output instead for separate 3.5 mm jacks we used to have on older machines. The jack is probably similar to American Audio Jack specification or like the one found on Macbook Pro. I have tried to use it with the Apple, HTC, Nokia earphones which ship with most of the smartphones. Microphone on the headset works the way it should.

Thing is that the headsets also come with remote controls to control volume and playback. I am sure that those key presses are sent to the Windows. I was hoping to catch those events and bind those to actual media keys so that I can control music playback. I guess this happens on Macs. I want to do the similar thing on the Windows. I'm just not sure where I can catch the events. Driver level? Application level?